# In Grafana, is there a way to add manual data?

Tags: grafana

Looking for a way to add manual data into Grafana. Want to display the results of a simple survey consisting of questions such as, "how old are you?", "how long have you worked here?" and so on. Summarizing the answers in grafana with graphs or similar would be tremendous.

Setting up a data source for this seems unnecessary, wondering if there is a plugin or something that allows me to do this? Not too familiar with the JSON behind the panels, but maybe it is possible through that aswell.

If anyone is wondering why I'm trying to do this in such a weird and unfitting way, it's for a school thing... :)

Answer (score 7):

You can generate graph by manually putting data. To do so:

1. Go to configuration: click on `Add data source`
2. Select TestData DB, Change the name and click `Save & Test`
3. Create new dashboard: Add Panel -> Add query -> select data source to `TestData`
4. Add data to string input field and Alias (i.e. How old are you?)
   [image: Grafana]

   Learn more about [TestData](https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/testdata/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSV plugin for grafana. I use excel and then save the data as CSV.
Below is snapshot of the data where we are portraying our test results.

[image]